# How to properly apply a Tween to a 3D rotation in Godot 4?

Tags: 3d, rotation, godot, tween, godot4

I have a `Node3D` which I would like to smoothly transition to a certain target rotation (given in euler angles, in degrees).

When I manually apply `lerp(...)` on all 3 dimensions of the euler angle vector (modulo 360) then it works fine. However, when I attempt to use a `Tween` (which seems to be the preferred way for such a use case in Godot 4) then I get crazy intermediate rotations - the final position is again fine.

Am I doing things wrong here? Can anyone give me an example of how to properly rotate a `Node3D` towards a given target rotation using a Tween?